# SetBackground for button in Fragment with androidx showing warning: argument getActivity() might be null

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

Trying to change button background color in `Fragment` but giving the following warning. I am using `androidx` in Android Studio version `4.0.1`

```
argument getActivity() might be null
```

Fragment Function

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    private void setButtonIcon(Button button, Integer drawable) {

        button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), drawable));

    }
}
```

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin this seems working. Thank you! set it as an answer. Might help someone else.

Comment: okay.glad to help! let me update in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation, we can try with **requireActivity()** or **requireContext()**

> **requireActivity()** Return the FragmentActivity this fragment is
> currently associated with.
>
> **requireContext()** Return the Context this fragment is currently
> associated with.

In the code side, they already checked like below

```
 if (activity == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to an activity.");
        }

 if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.");
        }
```

IDE won't show warning if we used those instead of getActivity() or getContext().